# Threading pattern search

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a program that essentially searches for patterns in a file.  It starts at level 1 which searches for all the different characters in a text file.  Then the algorithm takes those patterns and using the location of the previous patterns to find new patterns.  It is essentially a tree search of patterns.  I recently tried to thread the application and I am finding that it actually takes longer to process the more threads I add to the algorithm.  I did a performance test and noticed most of my time is being spent calling new.  That new could include my own explicit calls and internalized new called for vector resizes and push_backs.  Even the cpu usage goes up drastically when I use more cores but still translate to a quicker completion of the search.  Seems like the cpu is just working harder for no reason at all.  I am stuck at this point and I am not sure what to change but I think getting another set of eyes on this would be really helpful.  Sorry this is a bit vague and not a specific question.  I did not include the TreeNode class because I wanted to see if anyone would notice any bottlenecks in this function.  I can add the rest of the code later if nothing is apparent in this function.  Thanks

Here is the code that is threaded...

```
void ThreadedSpanLevelTreeSearch(long level, long startPatternIndex, long numPatternsToSearch){

Timing threadTimer;
threadTimer.setTime();

string localStream = fileStreamBuffer.str();
vector<TreeNode*> localTree;
TreeNode *leaf;
for(int i = startPatternIndex; i < numPatternsToSearch + startPatternIndex; i++)
{
    //countMutex->lock();
    //computationCount++;
    //countMutex->unlock();

    leaf = prevVectorizedTree[i];
    if(leaf != NULL)
    {
        vector<long> pList = leaf->GetPList();
        long pListLength = leaf->GetPListCount();

        for(int k = 0; k < pListLength; k++)
        {
            //If pattern is past end of string stream then stop counting this pattern
            if(pList[k] < localStream.size())
            {
                unsigned char value = localStream[pList[k]];
                //
                switch(currPattern)
                {
                    case PATTERNTYPE::NUMBERS:
                    {
                        if(value >= 48 && value <= 57)
                        {
                            leaf->addLeaf(value, level, pList[k]+1);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case PATTERNTYPE::ALPHABET:
                    {
                        if((value >= 32 && value <= 126))
                        {
                            leaf->addLeaf(value, level, pList[k]+1);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case PATTERNTYPE::EVERYTHING:
                    {
                        leaf->addLeaf(value, level, pList[k]+1);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                };

            }
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < patternArrayLength; z++)
        {
            if(leaf->GetLeaf(patternArray[z]) != NULL)
            {

                if(leaf->GetLeaf(patternArray[z])->GetPListCount() > 1)
                {
                    localTree.push_back(leaf->GetLeaf(patternArray[z]));
                }
                //deallocate
                else if(leaf->GetLeaf(patternArray[z])->GetPListCount() <= 1)
                {
                    delete leaf->GetLeaf(patternArray[z]);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    delete leaf;
}
countMutex->lock();
globalVectorizedTree.insert(globalVectorizedTree.end(), localTree.begin(), localTree.end());
countMutex->unlock();

//cout << "thread " << ceil(startPatternIndex/numPatternsToSearch) << " finished" << endl;
//cout << "time taken for core: " << threadTimer.getTime() << endl;
```

}

Comment: The way the data is stored can be very important, in particular the overall size and the locality can be important, so to get a better analysis you should add this info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The pool from which different threads allocate resources is the same. It is protected against concurrent accesses but using it from different threads causes this data to bound back and forth between the different CPU's caches, which costs performance.

There a few things to change:

- Avoid unnecessary allocations. Unless really necessary, avoid dynamic allocation. Also, a simple array or vector performs better than a linked list in almost all cases, they tend to have a large `n_0` in Big-O notation.
- Avoid copying. For example, `localStream` `pList` shouldn't be required.
- Avoid unnecessary reallocations, e.g. for vectors use reserve(). There is a point where the overhead for allocating too much outweighs the overhead of copying. This point also depends on the general use in your program.
- You could use an allocator that uses thread-specific pools.
- Avoid uselessly starting threads. If the amount of work for each thread is small, the startup and shutdown time could be dominant. In some cases, using a thread-pool could help.